# Add text to textbox macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Why doesn't this code work to add text to textbox? I am sure the syntax is off somewhere, but not sure where.

```
    Label5.Text = "Add Text"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say w/o a more extensive bit of code.

If the text box is actually an ActiveX Label (as suggested by its name), then like so:

```
Sub thing()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Some text"

End Sub
```

If it's a normal text box or other shape that can contain text:

```
Sub thing()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some text"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because its a shape.  Get the shapes collection and locate the label then access the `TextFrame2.TextRange.text`